# Does MADV_REMOVE result in a TLB shootdown?

Tags: c, linux, caching, shared-memory, tlb

I have a tmpfs with a number of large file-backed shared memory mappings. I'd like to be able to punch out any unused pages in the process that writes the files *without* causing major detriment to other concurrent processes. I understand that MADV_FREE and MADV_DONTNEED can/will result in a TLB shootdown, but I cannot find anything describing any potential ill effects of MADV_REMOVE.

Comment: It seems like it would have to.  "Subsequent accesses in the specified address range
              will see bytes containing zero."  It doesn't say "by this thread only", so it must be that all other processes/threads will also see zeros after the system call completes, and that can only be ensured by shooting down their TLBs.